# Is it general for such laptops to be loud?

Tags: laptop, fan

I have AMD A10 with 4 cores, AMD Radeon HD 8670M. (Asus x550ze) It's fan is loud. Is it normal for such powerful laptops to be loud or I made a bad purchase ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @whs says, laptops fans DO get very loud...

Some advice:

1. According to the Amazon reviews, a few people drilled holes into their cases:

> -Tends to overheat with a 35w CPU. I had to drill holes in the case just to get more air to the fan. It doesn't overheat now.

[[http://www.amazon.com/X550ZE-DB10-15-6-Inch-Graphics-Windows-Upgrade/dp/B00YR6BJLC]](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00YR6BJLC)
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/RIFIKNVUNLUOU/ref=cm_cr_pr_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00YR6BJLC]

2. You can also try replacing the fan, though it doesn't seem to be easy to do on your device and I'm not sure how effective that is...
3. On Windows, make sure no background processes/apps are using up too many resources by going to the `task manager`.
4. You can also try a Cooler Pad
5. You can also clean your laptop... Dust buildup often blocks airflow and leads to heating

Comment: Please do yourself a favor and check where your drilling... You DON'T want to end up with a processor with a hole through it... :P

Answer (score 2):

Laptops have small fans because of the space restrictions. If those small fans want to produce a larger amount of air, they have to turn very fast which makes them loud.

In addition you are dealing with an AND CPU which produces more heat than a comparable Intel CPU.

One thing you can try is a cooling pad. They lower the temps by 5 to 10 degrees according to my experience. But get a unit with it's own power supply - not USB powered.

http://www.bestbuy.com/site/laptop-accessories/null/pcmcat238900050004.c?id=pcmcat238900050004

Comment: Can I replace fan with maybe more quiet one ?

Comment: *AMD and @GeorgeJ, you can... but they don't get very quiet :(

Comment: Replacing the fan is probably counterproductive. The solution is a desktop in a nice big box with big fans that turn slowly.

Comment: @GeorgeJ quieter fans will almost always have a lower airflow and result in less cooling going on when what you really need is more.  It's a matter of blade surface area and blade speed and at the fan size you need most of the noise is caused by the fan cutting through the air. All the fans with similar airflows will be almost equally loud.  As whs says the best thing you can realistically do is to get more cool air to the existing coolers and hot surfaces by using a cooling mat.  I would do that *before* drilling holes into the laptop as suggested in the other answer.